# Video driver crashed and was reset

Tags: crash

when i was playing a game called Sea of thieves an error popped up saying "video drive crashed and was reset. make sure all of your video drivers are up to date. exiting...". at first i didnt think much of it and loaded back on to the game but then it kept happening again and again. at first it was once every week and then once every day and now it is happening every hour or so. keep in mind my PC dosent have the best specs and it is an all in one built in with the moniter so i dont have the best graphics in game. at first i tried updating my video driver but soon found out that it was already up to date. i next went on to the official Sea of thieves forums and support thinking that it was something to do with the game itself. i had a look on the forums and found people with similar problems but no answers. i then went on to customer support and when i clicked on " video driver " it brought me to the microsoft support page indicating that it wasnt the game but microsoft and the computer itself. i have heard suggestions of uninstalling and reinstalling the driver but i only have one and no back up driver so i am worried about what might happen to my PC. i have also heard about doing a factory reset yet i do not want to attemt it just yet as it is a last resort.  i am sorry if these sound like silly questions or descriptions just note i am kind of new to the whole PC thing. Thank you for taking the time to read this and please help me in any way that you can.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your graphics card may be overheating? Monitor the temps while playing.

Depending on the age of the card, it may be that you need to blow out the dust or replace the thermal compound.

Comment: There are many programs out there which you can use for this. Are you using a graphics card or on board graphics? What hardware do you have?

Comment: im using a graphics card and i have an all in one HP computer

Comment: Ok, who makes the card? eg. Nvidia or AMD?